# trigger input enter value respective li using jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Using jquery i want trigger click event to the li of respective input value

below is my input and li html . Whenever i add input automatically that add into li list.
So now i want trigger respective li element of input enter

```
<input required="" placeholder="Type Collection Name" type="text" class="cbxwpbkmark-field cbxwpbkmark-field-text cbxwpbkmark-field-cat cbxwpbkmark-field-cat-add">
<span data-object_id="2089" class="cbxwpbkmark-field-create-submit" title="Create Collection"></span>



<ul class="cbxlbjs-list cbxwpbkmarklist" style="" data-type="product" data-object_id="2089">
<li class="cbxlbjs-item" data-catname="452" data-privacy="0" data-incat="0" data-value="96"><span title="452" class="cbxlbjs-item-name">452</span></li>
<li class="cbxlbjs-item" data-catname="450" data-privacy="0" data-incat="0" data-value="97"><span title="450" class="cbxlbjs-item-name">450</span></li>
<li class="cbxlbjs-item" data-catname="448" data-privacy="0" data-incat="0" data-value="101"><span title="448" class="cbxlbjs-item-name">448</span></li>
</ul>
```

Currently i am using below jquery code.

```
jQuery('.cbxwpbkmark-field-create-submit').click(function() {
    var catname = jQuery(".cbxwpbkmark-field-cat-add").val();

    setTimeout(function(){ 
                            var successmesg = $('.cbxwpbkmark-form-note-success').html();
                            if(successmesg == 'Category created/edited successfully!')
                            {
                             //$('.cbxwpbkmark-toolbar-editcat').trigger("click");
                              
                              jQuery(document).find('[data-catname="'+ catname +'"]').click();
                              //$('.cbxwpbkmark-toolbar-listcat').trigger("click");
                           
                             }
                        }, 1000);
           });
```

but above example not working. Respective li not trigger automatically.anone have idea what exact wrong then let me know.

Comment: You are getting html here `$('.cbxwpbkmark-form-note-success').html()` so it will return you html tags as well but here `Category created/edited successfully!` you are comparing it with text ? Just change `.html()` to `.text().trim()` and try again

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is to trigger the click event of the `<li>` elements that are added dynamically. In that case, you need to make sure that the `click` event for the `<li>` is attached to a parent element or something.

An example would be:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('ul.cbxwpbkmarklist').on('click', '.cbxlbjs-item', function(){

    //.. write the things to do when an <li> is clicked

  });
});
```

Here, am attaching the `click` event on the parent `<ul>`. So when you add new `<li>` elements (of class `.cbxlbjs-item`) dynamically, the click event for the `<li>` will still work.

Apart from that, I would also point out what **@Swati** has suggested in the comments.

```
var successmesg = $('.cbxwpbkmark-form-note-success').html();
```

should be:

```
var successmesg = $('.cbxwpbkmark-form-note-success').text();
```

That's the proper way. But if there's no html tags inside the `.cbxwpbkmark-form-note-success` element, calling the `html()` would still return the text. But the safe way is to use `text()` method as it will return only the text even if there's any html tags in it.

Comment: when i enter value in textbox after save that value add into li with  data-catname attribute.. So i want to trigger only that respective li. Not need trigger all the li

Comment: @Praff can you please share the code for the `click` event you attached to `<li>`. I was talking about it. Not the triggering.

Comment: i m using wordpress. in that i want trigger click event

Comment: currently befault functionality is input text nd submit button there. when submit/create the category that added to the li but data-incat="0" . currently i need go nd click on checkbox for data-incat="1". So i want create or trigger click event on that respective li element enter in textbox automatically.